# Node.js, mongodb and filtered queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using the native API of mongodb and I'm trying to query the data on my collection.
This is my filter object:

```
{
    email: 'admin@email.it', 
    login: { '$exists': true } 
}
```

and this is one document that it should find:

```
{
    "_id": "5829cd89a48a7813f0cc7429",
    "timestamp": "2016-11-14T14:43:18.705Z",
    "login": {
        "clientIPaddr": "::1",
        "clientProxy": "none"
    },
    "userData": {
        "sessdata": {
            "sessionID": "CRTZaqpaUs-ep0J6rvYMBlQTdDakGwle",
            "email": "admin@email.it",
            "token": "3PlfQBVBoftlIpl-FizeCW5TbYMgcYTl4ZPTkHMVyxqv-TldWb_6U3eusJ27gtI64v7EqjT-KPlUUwkJK7hPnQ"
        }
   }
}
```

But the query doesn't return anything! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't return anything because the `email` field is in an embedded document within the `userData` field, hence it tries to look for an `email` field at a higher level within the document that does not exist.

To make this work, you need to modify the filter or create a new query object which includes the embedded field, albeit the key will be in dot notation field i.e. the query should resemble

```
{
    "userData.sessdata.email": "admin@email.it", 
    "login": { "$exists": true } 
}
```

You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to create the required field. For example:

```
var filter = {
        email: 'admin@email.it', 
        login: { '$exists': true } 
    },
    query = {};

Object.keys(filter).forEach(function(key){
    if (key === "email") {
        query["userData.sessdata."+key] = filter[key];
    } else {
        query[key] = filter[key];
    }       
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(query, null, 4));
```

**Output**

```
{
    "userData.sessdata.email": "admin@email.it",
    "login": {
        "$exists": true
    }
}
```

You can then use the query object in your `find()` query

```
collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    // access the docs array here
})
```

Comment: Ok, do you know if there is some thing to check the pair key:value everywhere it is?

Comment: When you say if you query with just the `email` parameter, does it return the above document or a different one? Most probably there are documents in your collection which have the `email` field at the top level fields. You can check that with the query `{ "email": { "$exists": true, "$eq": "admin@email.it" } }`

Comment: I edited my previous comment because, as you said, the document returned was another ... yesterday, during the tests, I saw both documents but, probably, the query was empty!